# Underscore _.template Uncaught Syntax error token

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm working on Addy Osmani's Backbone Fundamentals tutorial. http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#application-view

and am getting an "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %** " in Chrome.

It's pointing to a line in Underscore.js and also a line in my views/app.js.

In views/app.js, the line it's pointing to is:

```
statsTemplate: _.template( $('#stats-template').html() ),
```

It says "anonymous function" in the error message. This was copied from the tutorial, so I'm not sure why it's throwing an error. Thanks

Template markup:

```
<script type="text/template" id="stats-template">
    <span id="todo-count">
       <strong>
           <%= remaining %>
       </strong>
       <%= remaining === 1 ? 'item':'items'%> left
    </span> 
    <ul id="filters">
        <li> 
            <a class="selected" href="#/">All</a> 
        </li> 
        <li> 
            <a href="#/active">Active</a> 
        </li> 
        <li> 
            <a href="#/completed">Completed</a>
        </li> 
    </ul>
    <% if(completed) {% >
        <button id="clear-completed">Clear completed (<%= completed %>)</button> 
    <% } %> 
</script>
```

Comment: What does `$('#stats-template').html()` contain? Looks like a syntax error in there.

Comment: Implies a syntax error in the `stats-template` markup -- please post.

Comment: Ah, ok. Here's the stats-template code 

`<script type="text/template" id="stats-template">
      <span id="todo-count"><strong><%= remaining %></strong><%= remaining === 1 ? 'item':'items'%> left</span>
      <ul id="filters">
        <li>
          <a class="selected" href="#/">All</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#/active">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#/completed">Completed</a>
        </li>
      </ul> 
      <% if(completed) {% >
      <button id="clear-completed">Clear completed (<%= completed %>)</button>
      <% } %>
    </script>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The template markup has a space between `%` and `>` which is causing Underscore to balk.  This:

```
<% if(completed) {% >
```

Should be this:

```
<% if(completed) { %>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnTAx/1/)